# Table to autoadjust width to it's content

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have an excessive amount of content, which overflows.

What I'm trying to achieve, is to make the table readjust it's size based on the content of each td.

Example:
[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Qts87/1/)

In layman's terms, I'm trying to make it such that the dates will not be broken into 2 lines.

**Edit:** This only happens in chrome. Firefox renders them fine.

html extract

```
<div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="span10 overflow-table">
        <table class="table table-bordered table-condensed">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Date</th>
                    <td>2012-05-21</td>
                    <td>2012-05-22</td>
                    <td>2012-05-23</td>
                    <td>2012-05-24</td>
                    <td>2012-05-25</td>
                    <td>2012-05-26</td>
                    <td>2012-05-27</td>
                    <td>2012-05-28</td>
                    <td>2012-05-29</td>
                    <td>2012-05-30</td>
                    <td>2012-05-31</td>
                    <td>2012-06-01</td>
                    <td>2012-06-02</td>
                    <td>2012-09-28</td>
                    <td>2012-09-30</td>
                    <td>2012-10-04</td>
                    <td>2012-10-06</td>
                    <td>2012-10-08</td>
                    <td>2012-10-09</td>
                    <td>2012-10-10</td>
                    <td>2012-10-16</td>
                    <td>2012-10-18</td>
                    <td>2012-10-20</td>
                    <td>2012-10-23</td>
                    <td>2012-10-25</td>
                    <td>2012-10-26</td>
                    <td>2012-10-27</td>
                    <td>2012-10-29</td>
                    <td>2012-10-31</td>
                    <td>2012-11-01</td>
                    <td>2012-11-04</td>
                    <td>2012-11-07</td>
                    <td>2012-11-09</td>
                    <td>2012-11-10</td>
                    <td>2012-11-12</td>
                    <td>2012-11-15</td>
                    <td>2012-11-21</td>
                    <td>2012-11-25</td>
                    <td>2012-12-02</td>
                    <td>2012-12-04</td>
                    <td>2012-12-05</td>
                    <td>2012-12-07</td>
                    <td>2012-12-08</td>
                    <td>2012-12-11</td>
                    <td>2012-12-12</td>
                    <td>2012-12-14</td>
                    <td>2012-12-17</td>
                    <td>2012-12-18</td>
                    <td>2012-12-19</td>
                    <td>2012-12-20</td>
                    <td>2012-12-22</td>
                    <td>2012-12-24</td>
                    <td>2012-12-25</td>
                    <td>2012-12-26</td>
                    <td>2012-12-27</td>
                    <td>2012-12-28</td>
                    <td>2012-12-29</td>
                    <td>2012-12-30</td>
                    <td>2013-01-01</td>
                    <td>2013-01-02</td>
                    <td>2013-01-05</td>
                    <td>2013-01-06</td>
                    <td>2013-01-07</td>
                    <td>2013-01-08</td>
                    <td>2013-01-09</td>
                    <td>2013-01-10</td>
                    <td>2013-01-11</td>
                    <td>2013-01-12</td>
                    <td>2013-01-14</td>
                    <td>2013-01-16</td>
                    <td>2013-01-19</td>
                    <td>2013-01-21</td>
                    <td>2013-01-22</td>
                    <td>2013-01-25</td>
                    <td>2013-01-27</td>
                    <td>2013-01-30</td>
                    <td>2013-01-31</td>
                    <td>2013-02-05</td>
                    <td>2013-02-06</td>
                    <td>2013-02-10</td>
                    <td>2013-02-17</td>
                    <td>2013-02-18</td>
                    <td>2013-02-19</td>
                    <td>2013-02-23</td>
                    <td>2013-02-25</td>
                    <td>2013-02-28</td>
                    <td>2013-03-01</td>
                    <td>2013-03-03</td>
                    <td>2013-03-05</td>
                    <td>2013-03-06</td>
                    <td>2013-03-11</td>
                    <td>2013-03-13</td>
                    <td>2013-03-16</td>
                    <td>2013-03-22</td>
                    <td>2013-03-23</td>
                    <td>2013-03-24</td>
                    <td>2013-03-25</td>
                    <td>2013-03-26</td>
                    <td>2013-03-27</td>
                    <td>2013-03-28</td>
                    <td>2013-03-29</td>
                    <td>2013-03-30</td>
                    <td>2013-03-31</td>
                    <td>2013-04-01</td>
                    <td>2013-04-02</td>
                    <td>2013-04-03</td>
                    <td>2013-04-04</td>
                    <td>2013-04-05</td>
                    <td>2013-04-06</td>
                    <td>2013-04-07</td>
                    <td>2013-04-09</td>
                    <td>2013-04-11</td>
                    <td>2013-04-12</td>
                    <td>2013-04-13</td>
                    <td>2013-04-14</td>
                    <td>2013-04-18</td>
                    <td>2013-04-19</td>
                    <td>2013-04-21</td>
                    <td>2013-04-26</td>
                    <td>2013-04-27</td>
                    <td>2013-04-29</td>
                    <td>2013-05-06</td>
                    <td>2013-05-11</td>
                    <td>2013-05-12</td>
                    <td>2013-05-14</td>
                    <td>2013-05-15</td>
                    <td>2013-05-16</td>
                    <td>2013-05-17</td>
                    <td>2013-05-18</td>
                    <td>2013-05-20</td>
                    <td>2013-05-25</td>
                    <td>2013-05-29</td>
                    <td>2013-05-31</td>
                    <td>2013-06-01</td>
                    <td>2013-06-04</td>
                    <td>2013-06-05</td>
                    <td>2013-06-10</td>
                    <td>2013-06-13</td>
                </tr>
            </thead>

        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I know how to do it using jQuery. I'm trying to look for a CSS solution, however.

Comment: In what browser does the date brake in two lines? In your jsFiddle they don't, when I view them in Firefox.

Comment: Oh right. I forgot to mention that it only happens in chrome. Firefox renders them fine. Good call

Comment: Read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1893751/how-to-prevent-line-break-in-a-column-of-a-table-cell-not-a-single-cell

Comment: thanks. Gimmy. I guess i was looking in the wrong direction. If you can add an answer, i'll accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the CSS style [white-space:](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_text_white-space.asp)

```
white-space: nowrap;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
table td, table th {
    white-space:nowrap;
}
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Qts87/3/)**