# How to prevent word break in fixed layout table cell?

Tags: html, css, cell, word-break

I've set a  `table-layout: fixed;` on a table but the words within each cell are being broken onto a new line.

```
Eg:

Applicatio
n

Instead of:

 Application
```

I did try the solution of adding  `white-space: nowrap;` to no avail as [suggested here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1893751/how-to-prevent-line-break-in-a-column-of-a-table-cell-not-a-single-cell)

**Question:**
How to prevent word break in fixed layout table cell?

Table layout:

```
             <table  id="escalation" class="table table-striped table-bordered" cellspacing="0">


                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th style="display:none">ID</th>
                        <th>RID</th>
                        <th>Asset Name</th>    
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>

                        <tr>
                            <td>1</td>
                            <td class="td-limit">102345</td>
                            <td class="td-limit">Application Testing Break</td> 
                        </tr>

                </tbody>
            </table>
```

CSS:

```
#escalation {

    table-layout: fixed;
}

#escalation th {
    overflow: auto;
    font-size: 10px;
    color: #000000;
    border-right: 1px solid #7591ac;
}
.td-limit {
    overflow: auto;
    font-size: 11px;
    max-width: 220px;
    overflow: hidden;
    word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

Comment: You want the text to break anywhere in the word?

Comment: If you don't want to break word why did you set `word-wrap: break-word;` also your `table-layout: fixed;` won't work without `width`.

Comment: The value of `table-layout` actually has nothing to do with either the problem or the solution. Changing the value may *expose* the problem, that’s all. In my case, words were being broken with `table-layout: auto` but not with `fixed`. The accepted answer resolves the problem, regardless.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Apply CSS **[`word-break:keep-all`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/word-break)** to the cells.

```css
table { width:100px; border:1px solid black; }
th, td { word-break:keep-all; border:1px solid black; }
```

```html
<table  id="escalation" class="table table-striped table-bordered" cellspacing="0">


                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th style="display:none">ID</th>
                        <th>RID</th>
                        <th>Asset Name</th>    
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>

                        <tr>
                            <td>1</td>
                            <td class="td-limit">102345</td>
                            <td class="td-limit">Application Testing Break</td> 
                        </tr>

                </tbody>
            </table>
```

Comment: Why not link [`CSS` spec](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-text-3/#word-break-property)?

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu Why not link to one of the definitive resources that is much easier to digest than the spec.?

Comment: Check my link. I was just suggesting you would change your link to the spec. That's all. Trying to help :p

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu And, I've answered you by telling you that the MDN docs are just as reliable, easier to read and provides information about browser compatibility.

Comment: Ok, I see your point. My point was to link the official spec, even if not as nicely laid out. I was just suggesting. Take care and have fun. I appologize, I didn't see your second comment. I assume you edited it meanwhile. I never meant to disturb. I thought I was helping.

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu The spec. is great for times when you really need to dig into the minutia of something. But, MDN is widely regarded as the definitive resource for documentation on a wide variety of web languages and standards. It's comprehensive and it actually provides links to the appropriate standards documentation at the bottom of each page. So, in essence, you get two-for-one. Also, Mozilla (as you may know) oversees the JavaScript language (while ECMA standardizes it).

Comment: Well, I'm definitely biased here. It's probably because I'm expecting Firefox to respect web standards to the letter. I do apologize for the disturbance.

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu No browser respects web standards to the letter. But, you need to separate MDN and Mozilla Foundation. One is a huge knowledge base and documentation resource and the other (among other things) makes a browser that evolves like every other one does.

Answer (score 3):

You will need to add `white-space: nowrap;` to your `.td-limit`

```css
#escalation {

    table-layout: fixed;
}

#escalation th {
    overflow: auto;
    font-size: 10px;
    color: #000000;
    border-right: 1px solid #7591ac;
}
.td-limit {
    overflow: auto;
    font-size: 11px;
    max-width: 220px;
    overflow: hidden;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<table id="escalation" class="table table-striped table-bordered" cellspacing="0">


  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th style="display:none">ID</th>
      <th>RID</th>
      <th>Asset Name</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>

    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td class="td-limit">102345</td>
      <td class="td-limit">Application Testing Break</td>
    </tr>

  </tbody>
</table>
```