# Width of html text element when break line

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a problem with width of a text container.

I want to achive something like this:

[image]

When is red line I want end of `p`'s width. In this example width of p should be about 250px, not 100% of table (300px).
When text is in one line everything is ok

```css
p{
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: inline-block;
}
table{
   width: 300px;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div>
        <p>texttext textfdftext texttexttexttext texttexttexttext</p>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I can't see the image, can you please explain more what do you want to do?

Comment: click on link https://i.stack.imgur.com/IRMH1.png

Comment: Sry, I ve heared that I can't see photos here because of a proxy  :pp

Comment: In my js fiddle i select width of p element - I need the end of width where text ends. Now you can see about 50px empty space

Comment: when text is in one line width is ok look: https://jsfiddle.net/hysn1ubz/5/

Comment: Sry, i sent you the link without the update, take a look maybe you re looking for this,   https://jsfiddle.net/hysn1ubz/7/

Comment: It is my link, I need remove empty space after text "texttexttexttext", when text have two or more lines

Comment: I edited my comment take a look at this link : https://jsfiddle.net/hysn1ubz/7/

Comment: jsfiddle.net/hysn1ubz/7 - No, the problem is when text break lines

Comment: Look here https://jsfiddle.net/hysn1ubz/4/ - In this example table have 300px but p should have about 250px - when I change text p should have another width

Comment: As i understood, you want to make the width of the table dynamic, so maybe this would be helpful: in css file: replace "table" with "tr" and press run. so your css file will be as follow: p{
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: inline-block;
}
tr{
   width: 300px;
}

Comment: Table width is const 300px

Comment: You can change text "aaa aaa" - look border is "glued" to text - I want to the same in this examle when text have two lines  jsfiddle.net/hysn1ubz/4

Comment: Change from "<p>texttext textfdftext texttexttexttext texttexttexttext</p>" to <p>aaa aaa</p> and look on border

Comment: So, you want the width of the table to be <= 300 px?

Comment: Please clarify your question. What does "When is red line" mean? "When the text reaches the red line"? Do you just need padding-right or what?

Comment: That's waht I'm trying to do, Understanding the question :DD

Comment: I believe that's the answer to your problem, add this to the css file: td{
white-space: nowrap;
} as you can see in this [page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1893751/how-to-prevent-line-break-in-a-column-of-a-table-cell-not-a-single-cell)

Comment: No I want two or more lines, but I dont want width p all the time 100% when text have more than two lines.

Comment: YakovL - red lines it is place where should be right border in this example

Comment: Sorry to tell you, but what you want is simply not possible. There have been many similar question, but all with the same negative result. The reason is, that any block or inline-block element will extend to 100% width as soon as there's a linebreak in it (except if it has a fixed width, but that's not the case).

Answer (score 0):

> unfortunately, you can't correct the border position with **pure html and css code**

but you can use **javascript** to do this.

it's easy. just add an `< script >` tag in your HTML like the appended code below!

- **FIRST:** give the `border` attribute to the `< div >` element which is on top of < p > element, instead of the < p > element in CSS file!
- **SECOND:** change the display of < p > element to this:
  `display:inline;` in CSS file.

you can see the efficacy of **inline display**, [here](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_display_visibility.asp).

> < p > is a "**block**" displayed element which takes the whole line of it's parent. you have to set it's display to an "**inline**" to take the width of it's content!

- **THIRD:** use javascript to **get** the **width of < p > element**.
- **FOURTH:**  use javascript to **set** the **width of < div > element** to width of < p > element obtained in step 2.

you can test it in the code below:

**tip1**: I'd given the < div > and < p > elements an`id`to each one.

**tip2**: the **red border** of the result, is the border of `table` element.

```css
p{
  /* border: 1px solid black; */
  display: inline;
}
div{
  border: 1px solid black;
}
table{
   width:300px;
   border: 2px solid red;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div id="topOfText">
        <p id="text">texttext textfdftext texttexttexttext texttexttexttext</p>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>

<script>
function resizeBorder(){
  var textWidth = document.getElementById("text").offsetWidth;
  var topOfText = document.getElementById("topOfText");
  topOfText.style.width = textWidth+"px";
}
resizeBorder();  
</script>
```